# django urls : optional argument with default value is always None

Tags: python, django, url-routing

i have  a view for insert / update a table called `BankAccounts` in my database ... basically if `info_id` is passed to function its a `edit/update` if not and it has default value its a `insert` operation

```
def bankcreate( requset , info_id = 0 ):

    print(' -----> id is ' + str(info_id))
    errors = []
    default = None

    if info_id is not None and info_id > 0 :
        try:
            default = BankAccounts.objects.get(id=info_id , user_id=requset.user.id)
        except BankAccounts.DoesNotExist :
            default = None


    if requset.POST :
        VALIDATIONRULES = {} # some rules here 
        data , errors = validation(requset , VALIDATIONRULES)

        if not errors :

            if info_id > 0 and  default is not None:
                ba = default
            else :
                ba = BankAccounts()

            ba.bank_accnumber = data['bank_accnumber']
            ba.bank_cartnumber = data['bank_cartnumber']
            ba.bank_shabanumber = data['bank_shabanumber']
            ba.bank_title  = data['bank_title']
            ba.user_id = requset.user.id
            ba.save()

            return redirect('account-bank')
        else:
            default = data

    return render(requset , 'account/bankcreate-form.html' ,
    {'default':default , 'errors':errors} )
```

so as you cdan see the function should be accessible with or without the info_id 
this is my rules.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index , name='account-home'),
    url(r'^edit$', views.edit , name='account-edit'),
    url(r'^bankinfo', views.bankinfo , name='account-bank'),
    url(r'^bankcreate/(?:/(?P<info_id>[1-9]+)/)?', views.bankcreate , name='account-bankcreate'),

]
```

as you can see i'm trying to write a optional argument on the last line

```
url(r'^bankcreate/(?:/(?P<info_id>[1-9]+)/)?', views.bankcreate , name='account-bankcreate'),
```

but it doesnt' work ... and on the console in the function i get info_id as `None` not event the defined default value of 0 ... what am i doing wrong ?

this is my sample url

```
http://localhost:8000/account/bankcreate/1/
```

i've tried both

```
 url(r'^bankcreate/(?:/(?P<info_id>[1-9]+)/)?/$'
```

and

```
 url(r'^bankcreate/(?:/(?P<info_id>[1-9]+)/)?$'
```

but i got this error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/account/bankcreate/1/

Using the URLconf defined in paypal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

        ^$
        ^admin/
        ^account/ ^$ [name='account-home']
        ^account/ ^edit$ [name='account-edit']
        ^account/ ^email [name='account-email']
        ^account/ ^bankinfo [name='account-bank']
        ^account/ ^bankcreate/(?:/(?P<info_id>[1-9]+)/)?$ [name='account-bankcreate']
        ^account/ ^password [name='account-password']
        ^gateway/
        ^auth/

    The current URL, account/bankcreate/1/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Maybe adding a dollar sign at the end of the regexp solve your problem and please post a sample URL that doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani thanx , i've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra slash in your regexp (second one).

Change

```
url(r'^bankcreate/(?:/(?P<info_id>[1-9]+)/)?$'
```

to

```
url(r'^bankcreate/(?:(?P<info_id>[1-9]+)/)?$'
```

Comment: thanx , dorost shod ... i still get `None` instead of `0` for default value when not passing argument but i guess thats python !